# Emissivity not accounted for in Equilibrium Temperatures of Planets

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, power

I'm trying to understand how to calculate the Equilibrium Temperatures of Planets.
This is the beginning of my working for it...
[image]

However, whenever I look at external sources, (like [this Princeton source](https://www.astro.princeton.edu/~strauss/FRS113/writeup3/)), they don't account for the emissivity of the planet on line 3, and hence my calculations deviate from theirs. Why is this?

Comment: But the Princeton source accounts for $(1 - A)$ all over the place, corresponding to $(1-\alpha)$ or $e$ in your sheet. So I don't see any difference.

Comment: @ThomasFritsch It wasn’t accounted for when they were getting the formula for the power emitted by the planet. They only accounted for e when they were expressing power absorbed in relation to solar constant. I accounted for it in both, because I have the understanding that e matters for both absorption and emission.

Answer (score 2):

I have just been down this rabbit hole, and the formula you're looking for is:
$$
T_s^4 = \frac{L(1-\alpha)}{2 \pi \rho D^2(2-\epsilon)}
$$
Where:

- $L$ is stellar luminosity
- $\alpha$ is your albedo
- $D$ is distance to star
- $\rho$ is the Stefan Boltzmann Constant

Now, the natural follow-up question is "well how do I derive Epsilon?" and the short answer is: you don't. I went clear to a PhD in Atmospheric Science in my quest for that one. Epsilon is a "zero-dimensional" representation of all the thermal absorption factors on a planet. That includes surface composition, topography, atmospheric composition, weather, everything. For reasonable approximations, I've found that the logarithm of the surface pressure gives a fairly good $\epsilon$ approximation.

"Planetary equilibrium temperature" is a bit of a misnomer, as the full name would be better described as "if a perfect spherical blackbody was absorbing a certain amount of energy, what would be its temperature of emission?"